# connect failed: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: java, android, exception

I am developing one app, and what I think I wanna do is receive data from server database in android. So I started to run some tutorials. I found one that is doing pretty much what I want. 
But I am getting:

```
detailMessage   "failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)" (id=830021648792)
```

Whole code of this tutorial is here [link](http://veereshr.com/Android/AndroidToServlet)

Error occurs on :

`OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());`

I checked that:

- firewall is disabled
- ping is working
- connection string is exactly the same as when I run the servlet from server admin interface - `http://localhost:8080/Requestor/RQSRV`
  -the servlet is running

My configuration :

- Server : Glass Fish 4.0
- Android App - Developed in Eclipse
- Servlet - Developed in NetBeans

Comment: Is there something else listening on port 8080? What does `netstat -a -b` output for port 8080?

Comment: yes ,there are some apss linstening on that port

Comment: @AnthonyForloney 'Something else listening' wouldn't cause ECONNREFUSED. That means *nothing* is listening, or a firewall rule.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To access your PC localhost from Android emulator, use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1. localhost or 127.0.0.1 refers to the emulated device itself, not the host the emulator is running on.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses

For **Genymotion** use:  **10.0.3.2** instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: @Laalto can u please tell me where to change my address to 10.0.2.2 in code

Comment: For Genymotion 10.0.2.2 won't work.  You need to use 10.0.3.2, thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20914067/2162226

Comment: This idea worked fine with localhost....but in my office i have different host address 203.131.91.72
Here using url.openConnection() always throws an exception "failed to connect to 203.131.91.72 " 
What host or proxy permission is required to solve this problem??

Comment: i too keep on getting this error, i tried to download a file from local host but i keep on geting this error java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /30.30.30.38 (port 51749): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: I am also facing same issue,but I really don't understand why it is localhost/127.0.0.1:port  instead of localhost:port

Answer (score -1):

if you are using genymotion then go to command prompt type ipconfig
-find for Ethernet adapter virtualBox host-only network:
-find for Ipv4 Address..............192.1**.**.*
copy

http://192.1**.**.*/foldername/filename/filename.json or filename.php

to check if its working go to browser in emulator copy paste the url you should find the file which you are looking in your browser..

Sorry for English..
This worked for me hope this might help some one..
Thank u..