# 10.0.2.2:8080 in web browser in emulator is not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost, httprequest, easyphp

I have a wamp server in localhost. I tried to make http request from my android app. But cannot get it right. Many said 10.0.2.2:8080 will point to localhost from emulator. So i tried to open it in web browser from emulator. i typed in url as "10.0.2.2/cifi/test.php". But emulator popped error as "net:CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Need explanation: how to make my wamp server in local machine to listen 10.0.0.2:8080 from emulator's browser.

Comment: There is something you are not tell us. Is your emulator running in a Virtual Machine??

Comment: For Genymotion, 10.0.3.2 - from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20914067/2162226

Comment: Moved from answers to comments: It finally worked! I used "10.0.2.2:80/cifi/test.php". My wamp server listens only to that port. Thanks to everyone who wanted to help me!

Answer (score 4):

**Weirdly** enough, in my case, I had to turn on and off the *airplane mode* to get it working.

Comment: Still worked for me in 2023 on Android 13

Answer (score 2):

Your Wamp Server seems to be accepting only localhost connections.

Left click on wamp icon -> put online

Additionnally you should type a url `http://10.0.2.2:8080/cifi/test.php` instead of `http://1.0.2.2/cifi/test.php`

Comment: yeah i use easyphp wamp server. i started it...i can open it from my windows browser. But its not working in emulator's browser.And i nowhere mentioned i used "http://1.0.2.2/cifi/test.php"

Comment: You just wrote in your question : "i typed in url as "10.0.2.2/cifi/test.php". But emulator popped error as "net:CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT""

Comment: Have you tried the other thing I mentioned in my answer ? 
left click on wamp icon -> click `Put online`

Comment: @TheCopycat What is put online? It doesn't work again.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same problem and resolved it by executing:

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

That said, after I revoked forwarding, the host machine remained visible and all ports were working, so it is unclear *how* it works.

Make sure that

- You don't have a proxy set in WIFI settings
- If you do, then 10.0.2.2 is added to bypass without a mask
- That you didn't make a typo, like you already did in the post with 10.0.**0**.2:8080