# Displaying data in database without using json

Tags: mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Somehow I got arround with `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
having class not found exception error but I dont know if it works.  I
just added permissions, but now every time i run this app on my
emulator it keeps on catching to `SQLException` which I set to display
error2.

Why is it not showing my data from my database,,is there something wrong with my code?

```
public void connDB() {
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    try {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        String result = "Database connection success";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Scraped");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        while (rs.next()) {
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ":" + rs.getString(1) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ":" + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ":" + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(4) + ":" + rs.getString(4) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(5) + ":" + rs.getString(5) + "\n";

        }
        myTextView.setText(result);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        myTextView.setText("error1");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        myTextView.setText("error2");

    }
}
```

EDIT

This is what i found in logcat,,dang,haha so many i did not include the others but what i can understand is it didnt connect to the server or database.

---

02-11 23:56:13.716 14381-14381/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
02-11 23:56:13.716 14381-14381/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
02-11 23:56:13.716 14381-14381/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-11 23:56:13.716 14381-14381/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
02-11 23:56:13.716 14381-14381/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)

02-12 00:02:48.386 20185-20185/com.example.boneyflesh.connectnapls W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

> 02-11 23:25:37.714 2356-2371/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>
> ```
>                                             [ 02-11 23:25:37.717  2356: 2356 D/         ]
>                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaabfc5c0, tid 2356
>
>
>                                             [ 02-11 23:25:37.718  2356: 2356 W/         ]
>                                             Process pipe failed
>
>                                             [ 02-11 23:25:37.755  2356: 2371 D/         ]
>                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaabfc880, tid 2371
> ```
>
> 02-11 23:25:37.761 2356-2371/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   02-11 23:25:37.808 2356-2371/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 2371: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

---

Comment: You should start with logging those exceptions and including them in your question.

Comment: Formatting and grammar.

Comment: ive edited my question added what i found on logcat. what do you make of that?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind,, i solved it my self tuns out i just need to set my host address to 10.0.2.2 so my url look like this.

> private static final String url ="jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/db";

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341652/connect-failed-econnrefused)